# Program shows console output even though stdout and stderr are redirected

Tags: linux, unix, console

How does the vncpasswd program produce output on the console even though both standard out and standard error have been redirected to /dev/null?

```
$ vncpasswd > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
Password:
```

Edit: Here's a partial strace:

```
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 3
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_CONTINUE or TCSETSF, {B38400 opost -isig icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost -isig icanon -echo ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(5, 0), ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost -isig icanon -echo ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb7c3eda000
write(3, "Password: ", 10Password: )              = 10
read(3,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's opening the underlying terminal directly (something like `open("/dev/tty", ...)`). No amount of redirecting will get rid of that. If you don't want to see it, you'll have to run it not attached to a tty (e.g. through `cron` or something).

Answer (score 3):

It opens your terminal and writes there:

```
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 3
...
write(3, "Password: ", 10Password: )              = 10
```

Run it under `setsid` if you want to make that impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You're just redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null` try `vncpasswd &> /dev/null` instead.

Comment: I want them both redirected to /dev/null.

Comment: now that I think about it, your original answer should work as well. sry I don't know why..